# Index page with the same id as the slug

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug

I have wanted to ask this for a long time.. I have never worked out how to do this, is it possible?

---

**mywebsite.com/pots**             - This to be an index page showing posts or custom posts

**mywebsite.com/pots/myarticle**   - This to be an single post

---

I usually would just set it up like this to avoid any issues.

---

mywebsite.com/**pots**             - This to be the index page

mywebsite.com/**pot**/myarticle   - This to be the single post

---

I know it goes against the general slug rules, but surely there is a way to achieve this??? It just seems better for structure SEO...

Would love to know your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: This is perfectly possible, and is the default when registering a post type unless you specifically set different slugs for the archive and single posts.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, would you have any links of an example of how do to it? Or what terms to search for?

Comment: How are you currently registering the post type? Have you got that far?

Comment: I usually just use Custom Post Type UI. Im good with creating the CPT, unless theres a particular setting in there i need to use?